# Chi square test in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, python

- [image: Data Table]

  - [image]
- Doubt

How can I set chi-square test on city and brand as the column `city` and `brand` doesn't have number but string like `city` name and `brand_name`

I'm new to statistics so any hint will be helpful...

Comment: I came to this problem while solving basics of machine learning in python! I have taken screenshot for later learning I went through `chi square` and `t-test` practice problems but in practice problems data format was in numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chi-Square test works well with categorical data types. The target variable should be categorical, and the feature can be either categorical or numeric. In case of both categorial, you need to form a table with the counts/frequencies of each pair of configuration. This is referred as [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) as well.

Comment: Thanks can you please share the format of table I'm still finding difficulty in understanding...

Comment: There is a very good example in the Example section in the wikipedia page. Rows and columns are categories, and the middle entries are the frequencies of these configurations.

Comment: to my surprise I understood what you said in my dreams but have yet to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before you implement a Chi-squared test, you need to format your data as a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).

Comment: Can you please share like how and what should be the format of table...